# comparing parts of strings with a separating-character with each other

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got two tables with strings. Now, those strings consists of different parts separated by an `"`. For example:

table1:

```
-------------------
| 1 | hello"world |
-------------------
| 2 | hows"life   |
-------------------
```

table2:

```
-------------------
| 1 | world"hello |
-------------------
| 2 | hows"bro    |
-------------------
```

At the moment I got a query like this:

`select * from table1 inner join table2
on table1.id = table2.id
where table1.colum2 = table2.colum2`

This query should show both rows, because if you change the `hello` and the `world` from table1 you get `world"hello` which table2 does contain. How can I do this?

Comment: You should explain how comparison works with multiple ``"``, are those all equal: ``A"B"C"D"E"F`` and ``B"A"C"F"D"E`` and ``E"F"A"C"B"D`` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you column2 only has one `"` in the data, the below query will work.

```
select *
from t1
join t2 
 on t1.id = t2.id
 and 
  SUBSTRING(t1.column2 ,CHARINDEX('"',t1.column2 )+1,len(t1.column2 )) = reverse(SUBSTRING(reverse(t2.column2 ),charindex('"',reverse(t2.column2 ))+1,len(t2.column2 )))
 and 
  reverse(SUBSTRING(reverse(t1.column2 ),charindex('"',reverse(t1.column2 ))+1,len(t1.column2 ))) = SUBSTRING(t2.column2 ,CHARINDEX('"',t2.column2 )+1,len(t2.column2 ));
```

Hope this would help you out.

Comment: The table could have multiple substrings seperated bij an `"`

Answer (score 0):

For re-usability and clean code I would suggest creating a small function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitAndSwap]
(
    @input varchar(50),
    @separator char
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @separatorIndex int = CHARINDEX(@separator, @input)
    return 
        SUBSTRING(@input, @separatorIndex+1, LEN(@input) - @separatorIndex) +
        @separator + 
        SUBSTRING(@input, 0, @separatorIndex)
END
```

And then use as:

```
select * from @table1 t1 inner join @table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where (t1.value = t2.value or t1.value = dbo.SplitAndSwap(t2.value, '"'))
```

Comment: You are right. I missed the fact that you meant there could be multiple words separated by ". In that case, I cant imagine how u would do it because there will 'n' combinations to compare. What's up with the IDs. You are joining on them! I assume you insert strings based on matched IDs only, so why do you need extra where condition. I am not clear, it seems.